# css, js & image are not working in laravel5 on live server

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I uploaded my laravel 5 project from my localhost to a live server.In localhost it works correctly.But in live server it can't read any css, javascript, images. I add assets like css, javascript, images.. in to blade file such as:

FOR CSS,
`href="{{URL::asset('front_end/stylesheet/stylesheet.css')}}"`

FOR JS,
`src="{{URL::asset('front_end/js/tipsy/jquery.tipsy.js')}}"`

FOR IMAGES,
`src="{{asset('front_end/image/pizza.jpg')}}"`

And on .htaccess I use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Anyway, could someone please help me? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Do the css/js/etc files have permissions?

Comment: Whats your folder structure in live server?

Comment: Did you already check the URL of the CSS file after requesting an HTML page, did it point to the correct location? Where you able to open the URL of the CSS file in your browser directly?

Comment: You need to use raw tags. `{!!` and `!!}`, otherwise the output will be escaped.

Comment: Well, there was a little configuration problem. Now it's working correctly. Thanks to all.